# mysql_general_log with syslog server

Tags: mysql, wamp, syslog

Im running wamp on Windows 2008 X64 virtual machine.
I would like to save mysql's general_log file to a syslog server. Is it possible to setup a syslog server as the saving location?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a syslog server for MS-Windows? It is standard for unixoid systems (linux), I never heard there is one for MS-Windows based systems. Interesting. More and more good things are adapted by the MS-Windows world. Maybe, just may, the time may come when MS-Windows even gets a software management.

Comment: Do you mean you have a syslog server somewher else and want to send to it, or do you mean you want a syslog server running on windows.

Comment: Yes, i have syslog server elsewhere i want mysql putting the file there if its possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few products that will do what you want.  Intersect Alliance make a tool called [Snare](http://www.intersectalliance.com/projects/SnareWindows/), and there's also the open source [eventlog-to-syslog](http://code.google.com/p/eventlog-to-syslog/#utm_source=czanik.blogs.balabit.com&utm_medium=referrer&utm_campaign=blogs.balabit.com).